# Tag with no content does not receive highlight

Tags: html, css, highlight

I have a sections of text that users can add markers to.  These appear inline with an icon.  The issue I'm having is with highlighting (selecting text) the text with these markers.  The marker is set as a `background-image` property on an  `<i>` tag.

[image: Screenshot]

With the following styles the icon receives highlighting, but needs content to appear:

```
<i className="my-class">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</i>
```

```
.my-class {
  cursor: pointer;

  i {
   display: inline;
  }
}
```

This is a less-than-ideal solution though as it adds blank spaces to the text, which I still need to be able to reference.

I can get the icon to appear without content using these styles:

```
<i className="my-class">
</i>
```

```
.my-class {
  cursor: pointer;

  i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
  }
}
```

but then the element doesn't receive the highlight (screenshot above).

Is there either a way to get browser highlighting to work with an element that has no content or display these markers in a different way inline with the text so the browser thinks they have content?

---

Test:

```css
i {
  background-image: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/38961-200.png);
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

::selection {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Pubblication in <i></i> 1717, One Thoa...</p>
```

Comment: can you pose a code snippet here or jsfiddle so that we can better know your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using any pre-processors and I'm not familiar with them but shouldn't `className` be `class`?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio it could be `React`

Comment: I think you can: 1. use a font for your icons (icomoon?) or 2. convert any background to a tag image...

Comment: @uom-pgregorio, it is indeed React